# How to take data from two tables,one table not having common record

Tags: sqlite

Please Help I got a problem with join in my sqlite database,In that I 'm having two tables like userdetails and usertransaction tables,

userdetails having 5 records like userids 1,2,3,4,5 with their details

and 2nd table usertransaction having only 1 and 2 records.

I want to take userdetails with taht user trasactions sum...
if no transactions simply replace zero and remaing details.

query like this...

```
Select tblfarmers.farmerid,
       tblfarmers.farmerName,
       tblfarmers.mobileNumber,
       tblfarmers.Address,
       SUM(IfNULL(tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.presentadvance, 0)) as presentadvance
from tblfarmers
left join tblFarmerAdvanceDetails on tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.farmerid=tblfarmers.farmerid
where tblfarmers.farmerid='2'
  and tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.isactive='true'
ORDER BY tblfarmers.farmerid
```

Answer (score 1):

You are enforcing a condition in your left joined table that only rows that are actually joined can fulfill:

```
tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.isactive='true'
```

To avoid this you should remove this condition from the WHERE part and add it to the join condition.

```
    SELECT tblfarmers.farmerid,
           tblfarmers.farmerName,
           tblfarmers.mobileNumber,
           tblfarmers.Address,
           SUM(IfNULL(tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.presentadvance, 0)) as presentadvance
      FROM tblfarmers
 LEFT JOIN tblFarmerAdvanceDetails ON (tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.farmerid = tblfarmers.farmerid AND tblFarmerAdvanceDetails.isactive = 'true')
     WHERE tblfarmers.farmerid='2'
  ORDER BY tblfarmers.farmerid
```